# Is there a way to make G1GC collect more garbage per call?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am testing the G1 Garbage Collector to see if it is worth switching over from the CMS collector when running a particular application.

VisualVM 2.0.4 was used to monitor the CPU, heap and GC activity.

The application was run using the following JVM arguments:

`jvm-line-args=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xmx10G -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45`

Graphs for CPU, GC and heap space are shown below.
[image]

At around the 13:07 mark there is the first recorded GC activity where the used heap goes doen from 8912.9M(10220.0M) to 4871.7M(10224.0M).

The full log is shown below:

```
[GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.5685202 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 561.4 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 545972.2, Avg: 545972.4, Max: 545972.5, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.4, Avg: 0.6, Max: 1.1, Diff: 0.8, Sum: 4.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 165.3, Avg: 166.3, Max: 168.1, Diff: 2.8, Sum: 1330.1]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 40, Avg: 42.5, Max: 48, Diff: 8, Sum: 340]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 19.5, Avg: 22.2, Max: 23.7, Diff: 4.2, Sum: 177.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.5, Max: 4.2, Diff: 4.2, Sum: 4.3]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 368.6, Avg: 369.4, Max: 371.3, Diff: 2.8, Sum: 2955.2]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 2.0, Max: 2.6, Diff: 2.6, Sum: 16.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 13463.1, Max: 17469, Diff: 17468, Sum: 107705]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.8]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 561.0, Avg: 561.1, Max: 561.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 4488.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 546533.4, Avg: 546533.4, Max: 546533.5, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 1.1 ms]
   [Other: 5.9 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.8 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.6 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.3 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.8 ms]
   [Eden: 4438.0M(4438.0M)->0.0B(2048.0K) Survivors: 0.0B->556.0M Heap: 8912.9M(10220.0M)->4871.7M(10224.0M)]
 [Times: user=4.28 sys=0.20, real=0.56 secs]
```

After this, as shown in the graph above, there are many small GC spikes showing that the heap is only allowed to grow a little before the GC kicks in.

**Is it possible to call the GC less frequently, while freeing the same total amount of garbage?**

I tried using `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=75`, however there wasn't a noticable difference.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Standard output for smaller GC cycles:

```
[GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0807666 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 78.9 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 570672.2, Avg: 570672.3, Max: 570672.3, Diff: 0.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.2, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.5, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 1.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 36.9, Avg: 38.8, Max: 39.8, Diff: 2.9, Sum: 310.0]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 35, Avg: 36.6, Max: 42, Diff: 7, Sum: 293]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 38.6, Avg: 39.7, Max: 41.4, Diff: 2.8, Sum: 317.3]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 8]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 78.7, Avg: 78.7, Max: 78.8, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 629.8]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 570751.0, Avg: 570751.0, Max: 570751.0, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 1.5 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.5 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.1 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.2 ms]
   [Eden: 502.0M(502.0M)->0.0B(446.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->64.0M Heap: 5383.7M(10224.0M)->4954.7M(10224.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.63 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs]
```

Comment: you can make minor GC to be invoked less frequent (by disabling `AdaptiveSizePolicy`), but that means 1) your minor GC pauses are going to bigger 2) your `200ms` GC pause might be broken. In general, that is not advisable. May I know why you think that is appropriate to you?

Comment: From 13:10 onwards that sawtooth curve is only going up. Have triggered a manual GC to see if this is actually floating garbage? Your application might just be using that much memory, perhaps due to a leak.